# Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

So my code was working perfectly fine, no issues until now I'm getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)  
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)  
at TimeConstantAvg.main(TimeConstantAvg.java:26)
```

Here's my code

```
    ObjectInputStream ooois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("AvgTries.bin"));
     tries = (BigInteger) ooois.readObject();
```

And here's the way I've been saving the file

```
try {
FileOutputStream ooout = new FileOutputStream("AvgTries.bin");
         ObjectOutputStream ooout1 = new ObjectOutputStream(ooout);
ooout1.writeObject(tries);
 ooout1.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();  }
```

I had to forcibly shut down my computer but it wasn't while the file was being saved or loaded as far as I know and there are two other files that are loaded and saved the same way, neither of them are having any problems. Is it possible the .bin file was corrupted or something?

Comment: The file is corrupt. Delete it.

Comment: Dang, well I learned a hard lesson, always make a backup xD